# How to install librabbitmq in App Engine Google Cloud Platform

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip, librabbitmq

I've been trying to install librabbitmq in App Engine GCP without any luck. https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq

All other pip packages install properly if they are in the requirements.txt via my yml file, however, this package does not work (missing compiler, gcc, etc).

How do you install this in App Engine?

Comment: Any errors or other output you can share?

Comment: What the generation of AppEngine do you use? What version of Python? What is the content of your yml/requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both in Python2 and Python3 just in case, works ok for me.

Try to require a specific version,maybe that's your issue?

Here you have a simple requirements.txt, if that doesn't solve it give us more info.

Try this:

```
Flask==1.0.2
rabbitmq==0.2.0
```